# RMI Registry and Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, proxy, rmi, middleware

My project, that uses RMI, is so divided:

two interfaces, ISportello and IGestoreSportelli.

```
public interface IGestoreSportelli extends Remote {


public boolean sottoponiRichiesta (int id) throws RemoteException;
public void sottoscrivi (ISportello sportello) throws RemoteException;

}


public interface ISportello {
public boolean serviRichiesta(int id) throws RemoteException;
 }
```

Two classes that implements the logic of the application, and implements the interfaces: GestoreSportelliImplementazione and SportelloImplementazione

```
   public class GestoreSportelliImplementazione implements IGestoreSportelli{

public Vector<ISportello> sportelli = new Vector<ISportello>();
@Override
public boolean sottoponiRichiesta(int id) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Processo la richiesta: id:" + id);
    int size = sportelli.size();
    int i=0;
    boolean esito = false;

    do {
        esito = sportelli.get(i++).serviRichiesta(id);
    }while(i<size && !esito);

    return esito;
}

@Override
public void sottoscrivi(ISportello sportello) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("[GESTORE] Aggiungo un nuovo sportello");
    System.out.println("SPORTELLO: " + sportello);
    sportelli.add(sportello);

}

  }


 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class SportelloImplementazione extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ISportello{

protected SportelloImplementazione() throws RemoteException {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean serviRichiesta(int id) throws RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

 }
```

The second class is a stub (I will develop if further when I'll know why the program doesn't work as it is).

Two classes with main functions that "wrap" the previous two classes

```
public class GestoreSportelliServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    IGestoreSportelli gestore = new GestoreSportelliImplementazione();
    Registry rmi = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    IGestoreSportelli gestoreRef = (IGestoreSportelli) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(gestore,0);
    System.out.println("[GESTORE] AVVIATO");
    System.out.println("[GESTORE] " + gestore);
    rmi.rebind("gestore", gestoreRef);
    System.out.println("[GESTORE] Registrato");
    }
    catch (RemoteException r)
    {
        r.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}



public class SportelloServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    Registry rmi = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    ISportello sportello = new SportelloImplementazione();
    System.out.println("[SPORTELLO] : " + sportello);
    IGestoreSportelli gestore  =(IGestoreSportelli) rmi.lookup("gestore");
    gestore.sottoscrivi(sportello);
    System.out.println("[SPORTELLO] Sottoscrizione avvenuta");
    }
    catch (RemoteException r)
    {
        r.printStackTrace();

    }

    catch (NotBoundException n)
    {
        n.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IllegalArgumentException i)
    {
        i.printStackTrace();
```

system.out.println(i.getmessage());
        }

```
}

}
```

I run the classes with main in two differend prompt windows, and a third prompt windows runs the RMIRegistry. The SportelloServer class doesn't work. It runs into an exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@547d534d
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.sottoscrivi(Unknown Source)
at server.SportelloServer.main(SportelloServer.java:19)
java.lang.ClassCastException@547d534d
```

The #19 line is:

```
gestore.sottoscrivi(sportello);
```

Comment: Is there more of the stack trace?

Comment: No, nothing. I don't know what I did wrong and it's a very simple code.

Comment: Who printed the bottom line of it? The one that just reads `java.lang.ClassCastException@...`? And are all these classes and interfaces in the same package?

Comment: The last line was printed by system.out.println(i.getmessage())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both interfaces have to extend Remote:

```
public interface ISportello extends Remote{
public boolean serviRichiesta(int id) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Is the correct ISportello code